# Is there any way to differentiate between wlan and lan packets? That means how to know whether the packet is over wifi or lan (wire)?

Tags: networking, wireshark, telecommunication

*I am using wire-shark packet sniffer but I am unable to differentiate the packets over wifi and over LAN (wire)*

Answer (score 2):

First, this question is off-topic here because it's not about programming.

Second, when you do a wireshark capture, you have the option of selecting which interfaces you want to listen on, so you can choose wifi OR lan.

Third, if you need to listen on both, or have a capture file that includes both, the MAC addresses in the ethernet header should be different. In most cases the IPs will be different as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Actually I am capturing packets on gateway which is handling both wlan and lan traffic. Wifi router is connected to switch which is connected to common gateway. Now question is how can I differentiate the packets from wifi devices and non wifi devices hitting common interface at gateway. Is there any difference in Ethernet headers so that we can differentiate.

Comment: If it's a wlan *router* you're using, it will use a different IP address range which you can check for, but i guess you're using a wlan *adapter*, which just sends/receives ethernet packets over the air. There's nothing to distinguish wlan from lan in that case. If you're in a company network where all PCs are from the same vendor, they're probably going to use a distinct MAC address range for LAN and another for WLAN, but if you're in an internet cafe where customers bring their own devices, there's no foolproof way.